# How to convert dates into proper format and get the maximum, minimum range out of it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables where dates (from 2011 to 2014) are of different formats: 27-11-2013, 27/11/2013.

I have used

```
SELECT Convert (date,tran_date,103) as Valid_Tran_date FROM Transactions
```

which has converted dates into yyyy-mm-dd format but I am not able to fetch max,min and range of dates for further use.

I have answer these questions:
Q1. What is the time range of the transaction data available for analysis? Show the output in number of days, months and years simultaneously in different columns.

Q2. For all customers aged between 25 and 35 years find what is the net total revenue generated by these consumers in last 30 days of transactions from max transaction date available in the data?

Q3. Which product category has seen the max value of returns in the last 3 months of transactions?

Comment: You would probably do better to process this kind of thing in application code. Lesson learned.

Comment: Are you using MySql or SQL Server? Best remove the incorrect tag.

Comment: I am using SQL server sir.

Comment: The problem is you've chosen to store a date as a `varchar` and you aren't forcing the users to use a specific format. Are, however, all the dates in the format `dd-MM-yyyy` with the `-` interchangeable for a `/`? Could there be others? Maybe `MM/dd/yyyy` or `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Comment: Dates are only in two formats dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy. I want to store them as date in proper date formats.

Comment: @Anil What are the data types for your columns with date values - varchar? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, datatype is nvarchar. I want to convert it into date format so that i can run my analysis

Comment: @Anil What is proper date format? If you want to convert to date type, then CONVERT, CAST, DATEFROMPARTS are available options.

Comment: You ask 3 questions here about your data, but you haven't actually provided any; you actually start the question about changing the format/data type of your `varchar` date column (dates should be stored as a `date`, not as a `varchar`). For us to answer your questions we need to see some sample data (preferably as `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements, like in my answer) and expected results. **Neither of these should be as an image.** And, when you post the data, include your attempts as well.

Comment: sir I uploaded excel sheets into SQL and then created database. I am not getting how to share those files here.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default date format setting to `dateformat dmy` & do conversations :

```
set dateformat dmy

select cast('27-11-2013' as date)
```

Comment: Sir please see the questions above. I have converted dates using convert function but unable to proceed with the questions.

Comment: @Anil. . . This will resolve your date conversation issue.

Comment: Sir there are two columns having dates. How to convert the whole column and store them as dates? I tried using convert and cast too but going wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have the formats `dd/MM/yyyy` and `dd-MM-yyyy` then the solution is quite simple. You just need to change the data to the ISO format, and then alter your column's definition to `date`:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.DateTable (DateValue varchar(10));
INSERT INTO dbo.DateTable (DateValue)
VALUES('27-11-2013'),('27/11/2013');
GO
--Change data to ISO format:
UPDATE dbo.DateTable
SET DateValue = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,REPLACE(DateValue,'-','.'),103),112);

--Change to date datatype

ALTER TABLE dbo.DateTable ALTER COLUMN DateValue date;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.DateTable;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.DateTable;
```